# Microsoft Access horizontal scroll bar

Tags: ms-access, scrollbar, ms-access-2010

I currently have a form which contains 15+ columns which takes the entire length of the form 22". Every time I open this form, it seem to auto point to the last column. I want the user to start at the first column and so on. How do I control where my page opens up at? without using any code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your tab order the order in which you want your users to use your controls.
[image]

Additionally, you could consider making your form more user friendly and not have it be so wide. Scrolling is a pain and means that they need to know to scroll to fill in all the data. If you can fit everything on one screen (and 15 controls can very easily fit on one screen with no scrolling) then you can avoid this problem entirely.